# Mysql result into 2d array php

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli, multidimensional-array

```
$thearray = array
(
    //(0)ID, (1)NAME, (2)LOCATION, (3)PHONE
    array("0","Name 1","Nowhere 11","0004444"),
    array("1","Name 2","Everywhere 11","0005555"),
    array("2","Name 3","ThisPlace 11","0002222"),
    array("3","Name 4","NoPlace 11","0003333"),
    array("4","Name 5","ThatPlace 11","0001111")
);
```

This is how I used to store my information
I would then run through them to find what I needed
and display them using for example

```
echo $thearray[$i][4]
```

I want to do the same thing except store that information in Mysql
This is how far I've gotten but I keep getting strange errors and I cant output from the array

This is how far I've gotten

```
$result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM table");
$thearray = array();
while($thearray = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   $thearray[] = $thearray;
}
```

For some reason this isn't working for me, its like it isnt in a 2d array like I have above :S I can't simply echo it like I did before.

Comment: Can you elaborate? How can I get the results into a 2d array functioning the same as I used to.

Comment: To find something in database, you need to use database methods. This is what SQL actually for.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Dear Common, thank you so much for the down vote, I assume it had to be you! Please explain, to us mere mortals, how any amount of changes to this chaps query is going to improve his understanding that the data being returned from the query is not going to be the same shape array as the one he was manually generating.

Comment: @RiggsFolly there is no problem actually to get the data unchanged.

Comment: @YourCommonSense And exactly where in my answer does it look to you like I am changing the array that will be returned by the query. I was explaining how he could now deal with the data he was being handed by his original query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well first of all

```
while($thearray = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $thearray[] = $thearray;
}
```

Will keep overwriting the array and get very confused
try

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    $thearray[] = $row;
}
```

The array returned from your query is no longer a simple array, it is a associative array

i.e. it will look something like this:

```
$new_array = array
(
//(0)ID, (1)NAME, (2)LOCATION, (3)PHONE
    array('ID' => "0", 'NAME' => "Name 1", 'LOCATION' => "Nowhere 11", 'PHONE' => "0004444"),
    array('ID' => "1", 'NAME' => "Name 2", 'LOCATION' => "Nowhere 22", 'PHONE' => "0005555"),
    etc
);
```

So now when you want to use it you will have to use this sort of construct

```
$name     = $new_array[$i]['NAME']
$location = $new_array[$i]['LOCATION']
etc
```

or

```
<?php echo $new_array[$i]['NAME']; ?>
<?php echo $new_array[$i]['LOCATION'] ?>
etc
```